# SafeCracker Matrix re-ordering

Tags: safecracker, matrix

Im getting an error using safecracker and matrix when i try to re-order the rows, drag and drop doesn't work and using the drop down options returns this console error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'callback' matrix.js:147
```

EE 2.5.5
Safecracker 2.1
Matrix 2.5.3

Answer (score 1):

Oliver, this is a known problem and will be fixed in the next Matrix version. Meanwhile, could you shoot us an email at support@pixelandtonic.com referencing this thread and I'll make sure you get a patch immediately.

Cheers,
Andris